# Drupal 7 Chrome Login loop

Tags: google-chrome, drupal, authentication, drupal-7, phpmyadmin

After completing the installation of Drupal , I clicked on "view my website".
Chrome even though I sign in correctly it stays in the login page and the admin
bars are not visible.
Safari works , and as i checked the login attempts though Chrome are valid.
I cleared cache , I fixed tables @phpmyadmin and comment out the @cookie domain.
I am not sure how to check if the system time is off , or if this is actually the problem.

Thx a lot in advance

Comment: Do you have cookies enabled in Chrome?

Comment: Exact same issue with me - Chrome, MAMP, fresh installed Drupal several times and it won't let me login (access denied)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open a Chrome incognito window and try that, it seemed to work for me. Due to Chrome's overly aggressive caching, this was the only thing that worked for me. I'm still unsure as to root cause of the problem.